# Accordion jquery ui, not opening fully and generally buggy

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have a jquery ui accordion that was I was help to develop on here, the majority works fine but when you mouse in and out a few times it gets stuck, see screen shot below:

[Menu error http://jsfiddle.net/AJBweb1986/mZnv8/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/AJBweb1986/mZnv8/4/)

and here is the fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AJBweb1986/mZnv8/4/)

[image]

Comment: Ok found your problem just see my answer in a min :)

Comment: thank you I look forward to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it will work

See http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/mjHSJ/   it works fine now without any stuck...

**Replaced this**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        event: 'click',
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        autoHeight: false,
        icons: {
            "header": "closedacc",
            "headerSelected": "openacc"
        }
    }).on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).accordion( "option", "active", false );
    }).children('li').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).find('h3').trigger('click');
    });

});
```

​

**With this**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        event: 'click',
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        autoHeight: false,
        icons: {
            "header": "closedacc",
            "headerSelected": "openacc"
        }
    }).children('li').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).find('h3').trigger('click');
    });

});
​
```

Actually I think `mouseleave` and `mouseenter` events were creating some kind of bottle neck situation so I removed one :P

Comment: Thank you that has fixed the issue only problem is that it now doesn't collapse on mouse out, do you know how to include this with out cause it to trip over itself